# Spring boot actuator MySQL database health check

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have designed one demo spring boot application CRUD operation with MySQL database. My application.properties file is as follow.

```
spring.boot.admin.url=http://localhost:8081
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springbootdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
endpoints.health.sensitive=false
management.health.db.enabled=true
management.health.defaults.enabled=true
management.health.diskspace.enabled=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

POM.xml for the spring actuator is as follow.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

When I try to hit the url "http://localhost:8080/health", I am getting {"status":"UP"} as response. I want to monitor my database (MySQL) with spring boot actuator. I want see my database status.

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: Do you need status of database? could u please explain more

Comment: yes, I need database status, and I am not much aware what maximum details of database we can grab using spring boot actuator as I am new to spring boot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would check [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-health-access-restrictions) - Exposing the full details anonymously requires to disable the security of the actuator.

If that's not what you want, you can take full control of the security and write your own rules using Spring Security.

Answer (score 5):

Add this configuration to your **application.properties** file

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Answer (score 3):

In spring version 2.2.x is:

```
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

by default this prop has value never.

Answer (score 2):

I have used my own way of checking a database connection. Below solutions are very simple you can modify as according to your need. I know this is not specific to actuators, though it is the kinda same approach to solve when you don't wanna use the actuators.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/db/")
public class DbHealthCheckController {
@Autowired
JdbcTemplate template;

private final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

@GetMapping("/health")
public ResponseEntity<?> dbHealthCheck() {
    LOGGER.info("checking db health");
    try {
        int errorCode = check(); // perform some specific health check
        if (errorCode != 1)
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new ApiResponse(false, "down"));
        return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(true, "Up"));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.error("Error Occured" + ex.getMessage());
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body(new ApiResponse(false, "Down"));
    }
}

   public int check() {
     List<Object> results = template.query("select 1 from dual", new 
           SingleColumnRowMapper<>());
          return results.size();
     }
}
```

`ApiResponse` is a simple POJO class with 2 attributes `Boolean success
 and String message`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring security, then security is by default enabled for actuator.

Add this in your properties file -

```
management.security.enabled= false
```

OR

Add username and password in properties file -

```
security.user.name= username
security.user.password = password
```

and use these credentials to access actuator endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

When call http://localhost:8080/actuator endpoint, there must be a endpoint like below.

```
"health-component": {
  "href": "http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/{component}",
  "templated": true
}
```

In my case i use mongodb in my application. And i call http://localhost:8080/actuator/health/mongo endpoint it returns mongodb health.

```
{
  "status": "UP",
  "details": {
     "version": "2.6.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What determines the component name? EG if I want to check on the JPA or datasource connection?

Comment: This [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/actuator-api/htmlsingle/#health-retrieving) shows the response structure, **The components that make up the health.**, but I did not find the component name list

Comment: https://reflectoring.io/spring-boot-health-check/ This blog post is much detailed